Drizzle kit migration and pushing
i want to push to my db 'neon postgresSQL' a new table "products".
// Define the products table
export const products = pgTable("products", {
  id: serial("id").primaryKey(),
  title: text("title").notNull(),
  description: text("description").notNull(),
  price: real("price").notNull(),
  createdAt: timestamp("created").defaultNow(),
});

i want to add it to an existing schema file
//other tables .... 

// Define the twoFactorTokens table
export const twoFactorTokens = pgTable(
  "twoFactorToken",
  {
    id: text("id")
      .notNull()
      .$defaultFn(() => createId()),
    token: text("token").notNull(),
    expires: timestamp("expires", { mode: "date" }).notNull(),
    email: text("email").notNull(),
    userId: text("userId").references(() => users.id, { onDelete: "cascade" }),
  },
  (verificationToken) => ({
    compoundKey: primaryKey({
      columns: [verificationToken.id, verificationToken.token],
    }),
  })
);

//here i added the product table


my scripts are:
"db:generate": "npx drizzle-kit generate",
"db:push": "npx drizzle-kit migrate",

when i run the first command i got this file in the server folder:0008_peaceful_meltdown.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "products" (
    "id" serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "title" text NOT NULL,
    "description" text NOT NULL,
    "price" real NOT NULL,
    "created" timestamp DEFAULT now()
);


then i push it to the db i got:
applying migrations...error: column "userId" of relation "twoFactorToken" already exists
what should i do?

If anyone is having this issue, i rolled back the tables and added the new modification at one push
